# How to prevent jerkiness on mouseenter/leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying to develop a list of projects, which on mouseenter/leave triggers a function. Currently on mouse enter the background block slides out of view to the right and on mouse leave the background block slides back into view. This works as expected, but when I enter and leave multiple times, the animations trigger and jerk around - loosing the smooth scroll effect that I'm trying to achieve. How would I go around preventing the jerkiness, I've tried adding a 'disable' class, but this doesn't seem to work. Any and all advice would be helpful.

**jQuery V1:**

```
  project.mouseenter(function() {
    var project = $(this).hasClass('disable');
    if(!project){
      var colourDuration = 750, colourDelay = 550;
      $(this).find('.colour-block').stop(true,false).velocity({left:'100%'},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay, complete: function() {
        $(this).addClass('disable');
      }});
      $(this).find('p').stop(true,false).velocity({height:'26px'},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
      $(this).find('button').stop(true,false).velocity({height:'26px'},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
    }
  });
  project.mouseleave(function() {
    var project = $(this).hasClass('disable');
    if(!project){
      var colourDuration = 750, colourDelay = 550;
      $(this).find('.colour-block').stop(true,false).velocity({left:0},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay, complete: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('disable');
      }});
      $(this).find('p').stop(true,false).velocity({height:0},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
      $(this).find('button').stop(true,false).velocity({height:0},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
    }
  });
```

**jQuery V2:**

```
  project.hover(function() {
    var colourDuration = 750, colourDelay = 550;
    $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity({left:'100%'},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay});
    $(this).find('p').velocity({height:'26px'},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
    $(this).find('button').velocity({height:'26px'},{duration: 500, delay: 225});
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity('stop').velocity('reverse');
    $(this).find('p').velocity('stop').velocity('reverse');
    $(this).find('button').velocity('stop').velocity('reverse');
  });
```

**Velocity JS**

```
http://velocityjs.org/
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see the issue - the code on it's own does not help visualise your actual problem

Comment: Runs fine on my PC with Chrome... If you add event handlers, make sure you only add them once - I think this might add one every time: $(this).find('.colour-block').stop(true,false). **velocity(...)**

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572056/how-to-use-velocity-js-in-hover - use the reverse

Comment: Runs fine on Chrome latest for me